# Check predicate of previous value less than x value; Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
test = {'temperature' : [15, 26, 24, 23, 26, 29, 25, 24, 19, 16, 15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
    
print(df)

  
record = []

for i in df:
 if df['temperature'][df.loc[df['temperature'].lt(df['temperature'])] -1] > df['temperature'][df.loc[df['temperature'].le(df['temperature'])]]:
    record.append(df['temperature'])
 else:
    record.append(np.nan)

df['record'] = record

print(df)
```

I am having a nightmare creating a new column based on the following logic.

Find the 'value with the highest index less than temperature' and print this value in new column only if the 'value in previous index of value with the highest index, less than temperature, is greater'

Please note:-Only values in row indexes less than current 'temperature' index are to be used

Step 1:

For each value, I want to find the value with the highest index less than temperature, for example the index of the most recent value less than`25` is `3` (value `23`)

Step 2:

Then I want to check whether the value in the index before, is greater than or less than value found. Following on from example in Step 1. the value in the index before `3` is `24` which is greater than `23`

Step 3:

Create new column printing value that satisfies steps and `np.nan` where steps are not met.

I can't get my head around this.

The output would be as shown below:

```
    temperature  record
0            15     NaN
1            26     NaN
2            24     NaN
3            23     NaN
4            26     23
5            29     23
6            25     23
7            24     23
8            19     NaN
9            16     NaN
10           15     NaN
```

Comment: On *Step 2*, I dont think **24** is greater than **25** but I've been wrong before.

Comment: @karlphillip thanks I've just corrected that error

Comment: What do you mean by "most recent value less than it"? Why is it 23, and not 24?

Comment: @navneethc using `25` as an example, I would looking at numbers before it ie. `15, 26, 24, 23, 26, 29` so the 'most recent..' is the one closest; in this case `23`

Comment: most recent means highest index?

Comment: @SyntaxError 'highest index' Yes!! That is a much better and more concise explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas often makes it possible to solve problems using elegant one-liners. I am not sure this is the case, though, so let us go the boring way with hand-written loops:

```py
def find_nightmare_value(values, idx):
  j = idx - 1
  while j >= 1 and (values[j] >= values[idx] or values[j-1] <= values[j]): j -= 1
  return values[j] if j >= 1 else np.nan

def nightmare_transform(values):
  return [find_nightmare_value(values, i) for i in range(len(values))]
```

Usage in your example:

```
df['record'] = nightmare_transform(df.temperature)
```

Note that this implementation is quadratic and for a column of constantly decreasing values of length significantly more than 10K or so may become impractical. Finding a linear-time solution to the problem is a nice puzzle (which, I suspect, is not too relevant for your use case, though).

Comment: Many thanks . I applied your functions and it worked almost perfect, however index row 5 prints `NaN` instead of `23`.
Also the example dataframe is a scaled down version; the full dataframe would in some cases have 5,000 to 250,00 rows

Comment: I'm not sure why row 5 should not print NaN. The value at 4 (26) is smaller than value at 5 (29), yet this value is greater than the previous one.

Comment: row index 5 should print `23` because it has the highest index row with a value less than `29` and a value immediately before it that is higher (value `24` index 2)

Comment: 26 at index 4 is also less than 29 and comes later than 23.

Comment: yes.. but the value of the number immediately before `26` in index row 4 is not greater, therefore doesn't satisfy the rule

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood your explanation with clearly separated "steps" and the correct solution would be different. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Sorry my explanation could have been better

Comment: the changes you made got it working. Great stuff. I would be interested to know whether you had any more thoughts on the 'liner-time' solution

Comment: On another note, I would be interested to get a another column which prints the row index of where the value of `df['record']` originates from for a sanity check

Comment: @windwalker, to get the row index, modify the `find_nightmare_value` function to return `j` rather than `values[j]` appropriately. I had a linear-time solution written out for my initial understanding of the problem, after your clarification that solution did not apply anymore, and adapting it to the new requirement would have made it longer than reasonable for this answer. Let's keep it as an open puzzle for those who are into this kind of stuff ;)

Comment: My sanity is now in check! Cheers mate

Comment: I am seeking to further adapt this function and make the `len` in this line dynamic ..........`return [find_nightmare_value(values, i) for i in range(len(values))]` .....shorten the `len` to only rows that are within 3 months of current row date

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to stick closely to your original code.  However, I assume record is meant to be a new record temperature.  However, your instructions seem to only care is the current temp is greater than the previous temp.  If you want a record temp, you want to know that the new temp is greater than all previous temps. So, that is the assumption I used in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
test = {'temperature' : [15, 26, 24, 23, 26, 29, 25, 24, 19, 16, 15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
    
print(df)

record = []

record_temp = -10000
for temp in df['temperature']:
    if  temp > record_temp:
        record.append(temp)
        record_temp = temp
    else:
        record.append(np.nan)

df['record'] = record
print(df)
```

Comment: Find the 'value with the highest index less than temperature' and print value in new column only if the 'value in previous index of value with the highest index, less than temperature, is greater' @cadvena Hopefully this is a better description of what I am seeking to achieve

Comment: So, if the current index is 6, the temp = 25.  Stepping back index 5 is 29, which is > 25.  Next, index 4 = 26, which is > 25.  Next, index 3 = 23, which is < 25, so you want that value.  If so, then shouldn't record = 15 for index 1 (temp = 26) since it is a prior row and also has a lower value?

Comment: when there is only less than two index rows before current 'temperature' value than the output should be NaN since 'step 1' and 'step 2' individually utilize previous indexes